# Weird display on dialog.show()

Tags: android, android-dialog

Firstly, I have no error no stack but shapeless view on the right side of Dialog. This view does not disrupt the dialog but causes a shapeless view. My Dialog:

```
public Dialog DialogShow(int position){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Main.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(dialog.getWindow().FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_news_detail, null);
    dialog.setContentView(layout);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    **dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.WHITE));**
    ImageView newsImage = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.news_image);
    TextView newsTitle = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView newsContent = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.icerik);

    newsImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.news);

    newsTitle.setText(itemNode.get(position).path("Title").asText());
    newsContent.setText(itemNode.get(position).path("Content").asText());

    return dialog;
}
```

I am calling this dialog with the code:

```
final Dialog dialog = DialogShow(4);
dialog.show();
```

I solved this shapeless view problem with deleting the pointed line on my code. With deleting it, I display a clear dialog on my app. But, I'm curious about that why this deleted line made my view bad? It seems just setting the background color.

Comment: Did you set a custom `Theme` to your `Dialog` in style.xml? Because why don't you set a background color with `android:windowBackground`?

Comment: `dialog.getWindow()` only works after showing the dialog. Have you tried doing the same after `dialog.show();` Try and let me know whether it works or not ?

Comment: I tried just now cutting that line to below of `dialog.show();` Same problem continues @pyus13

Comment: No, you don't necessarily need it. But this way avoid to make it dynamically. You'll able to create a background drawable/color without intervention in the code

Comment: It sounds reasonable but i already know this. i want to learn why this code line behaves like this, no error no stack but why dialog has weird views on its right and bottom. @Fllo